# Division of two incomplete gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

I am working on an equation that needed to divide two incomplete gamma functions. They are just different by the first term  as they are IG(a,b) and IG(2a,b). Is there any closed form or simple approximation for the division?

Comment: If the only tag you found to apply to your question was “self”, perhaps it's a sign that you are asking on the wrong site?

Comment: I was looking for self-study but it did not exist, sorry.

Comment: Over the reals, complex or integers?

Comment: thanks. Over the real